# Creating 3D scatter plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, 3d, scatter-plot

I have my data in the variable data:

```
data = read.csv("datafile.csv")
```

`datafile.csv` is of the form:

```
x1,y1,z1
x2,y2,z2
.....
xn,yn,zn
```

How do I create a 3D scatter plot? (the scale etc. should be automatically taken care of).

Comment: Google '3d scatter plot R' ie package scatterplot3d

Comment: -1 : Seriously, ten seconds on Google would give you a number of packages with simple functions: `lattice` `scatterplot3d` `rgl` `Rcmdr`.

Answer (score 4):

Let's simulate a data example.

```
#create data observations for x, y and z
x = c(10,09,03,04,05)
y = c(08,04,07,08,09)
z = c(15,10,11,09,09)

#join vectors x, y and z directly into a data.frame as suggested by @thelatemail.
data=data.frame(x,y,z)
```

The object `data` is supposed to simulate the data you have. See it below

```
data

   x y  z
1 10 8 15
2  9 4 10
3  3 7 11
4  4 8  9
5  5 9  9
```

The answer:

```
library(scatterplot3d)
scatterplot3d(data$x,data$y,data$z)
```

[image]

See `?scatterplot3d` to explore other arguments inside this function.

Comment: What do there numbers mean here?  a = c(10,09,03,04,05)
b = c(08,04,07,08,09)
c = c(15,10,11,09,09)

Comment: @hrs, They are just examples to simulate a data.frame (something like you would have in `data`).

Comment: `data.frame(cbind(...))` is a really bad habit to get into as it creates a matrix first and coerces all the data to one type. Also, is it not strange to create `a/b/c` and then map them to `x/y/z`? Surely starting with `x/y/z` and then using: `data.frame(x,y,z)` would be preferable.